# Angular on NodeJS backend via HTTPS

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express, https

I have a frontend (Angular 7, ngx-admin) and a backend (nodeJS, express).

**The problem**: angular uses https and communicate with the backend via http. This cause this issue:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xyz' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:56231/api/MyAPI'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

So what I did then was making the backend supporting https. Something (very) similar to this:

```
const app = express();
var https = require('https')

// ... 

https.createServer({
}, app)
.listen(56231, function () {
  console.log('Backend running on port: 56231');
})
```

and then changing the angular code (calling the backend) from HTTP to HTTPS.

```
return this.http.post('https://0.0.0.0:56231/api/MyAPI', form)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .catch(this.error);
```

}

It is clear that I'm missing some steps ... any light?

Comment: How does the angular app get served over HTTPS? Is the app coming from a different server?

Comment: front-end and back-end are on two different (virtual) machines but this is not relevant. Point is: when the front-end tries to do http.post to the backend it doesn't work ... question is: what is the setup to get this working between angular and nodejs?

Comment: It's not clear what is not working when you move the API server to HTTPS, you haven't provided any details in that regard. I asked how the app was being served over HTTPS because you don't need to change the API code if the app is served over HTTP. You're having a "Mixed Content" error because the browser will not attempt to make insecure requests when in a secure context (e.g. when youre browsing over HTTPS). Regardless of HTTP vs HTTPS you will still need to handle CORS in the API since the app lives on a different domain, perhaps this is where things are breaking down?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the port. your node server is running on 3131.  you send a post request to 56321

Comment: Good catch but was just a mistake/typo here. I’m sure something must be done on the angular side

Comment: Please change your code to what you are actually using / trying and paste the current error